# Excel Match and If functions

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to match two columns in a spreadsheet if some conditions hold on other columns in the spreadsheet. For example I want to match column A to column E if column B = column H, column C = column F and column D = column G in the following:

```
Col A          B        C     D         E       F        G       H         I
    Product ID Currency Amt   Maturity  ARR ID  ARR Amt  Expiry  Currency  ANTICIPATED RESULT
    A          USD      100   2         Z       0        1       USD       TRUE
    B          USD      0     2         Q       15       1       USD       TRUE
    C          USD      0     2         A       100      2       USD       TRUE
    F          USD      120   2         C       0        2       USD       TRUE
    E          USD      37    2         B       0        2       USD       TRUE
    D          USD      25    2         E       37       2       USD       FALSE
    G          EURO     0     2         D       27       2       USD       TRUE
    H          EURO     0     5         F       120      2       USD       TRUE
    J          EURO     50    4         R       0        4       EURO      NA
    I          EURO     1000  1         T1      0        3       EURO      NA
    L          EURO     12    7         K       15       1       EURO      TRUE
    M          GBP      35    5         J       50       4       EURO      TRUE
    A2         GBP      15    2         N       12       4       EURO      FALSE
                                        O       14       1       USD       NA
                                        P       0        2       USD       NA
                                        R       0        3       USD       NA
                                        S       55       4       USD       NA
                                        T2      66       1       USD       NA
                                        A2      15       2       USD       NA
                                        G       0        2       EURO      NA
                                        H       0        5       EURO      NA
                                        I       1000     1       EURO      NA
                                        L       12       7       EURO      NA
                                        M       35       5       GBP       NA
```

The anticipated result is also given in the last column.

Please your help with the correct and functioning formula will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What did you do to find the answer? You can't just ask for a formula, without even showing your own work/formula. Acccording to the stackoverflow help page: "Don't ask about... Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)"

Comment: Check the edit please. The table had tabs which didn't go well with the markdown. I tried to fix it but can't be sure if everything's still correct.

Comment: Can't get the logic behind what are you comparing to what.

Comment: The first example Column A = A which is not equal to column E = Z, then how are you getting Anticipated Answer as true?

Comment: this is easy, but as what jacob said you should've shown what you've tried. Here's my tip: Concatenate the values in `Column A to D` and put in a helper column (any column without value). Do the same with `Columns E to H` but the same order as the how you concatenate your values in `Columns A to D`. Put in another helper column. Then apply the `Match` or `Vlookup` function on the results of two helper columns. Hope this gets you started.

Comment: Thanks all for your comments.

Comment: Please see the logic behind this question below:

Comment: Example : Product 'A' can be matched with ARR Id 'A'on row 3 because Product A amount = 100, ARR ID A amount =100, currency for both product 'A' and ARR ID 'A; is USD and also product'A' maturity = ARR ID 'A' Expiry. This is reason why the anticipated result is 'True'. I am really sorry if i was not clear before. I have tried to used the following formular but it was not working: =ISNUMBER(IF($B$2=$H$2,$C$2=$F$2,$D$2=$G$2),MATCH(A2,E2:E25,0)).Please your help will be highly appreciated. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Basically as advised by @L42.**

Add columns to concatenate strings to create indices:-

in K2: `=A2&"|"&B2&"|"&C2&"|"&D2`
in L2: `=E2&"|"&H2&"|"&F2&"|"&G2`

both copied down to suit. In M2 and copied down to M14:

```
=IFERROR(MATCH(K2,L:L,0),"FALSE")
```

to return the row number where E:H data matches A:D data in the row where that row number appears.

Indicates that `ANTICIPATED RESULT` were not all correct, Q details are incomplete or incorrect, or I have misunderstood.

To output instead only TRUE, FALSE or NA change formula in M2 to:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A2),"NA",IFERROR(MATCH(K2,L:L,0)>0,"FALSE"))
```

and copy down to M25.

[image: SO20989545 example]